# how to increase column and row of protected sheet apache poi in java

Tags: java, apache

**1.** How to protect specific cell and we can also be able to increase the column and row of protected sheet using Apache poi in java

**2.** Can I make specific cell read only if we open ms office does not allow editable using `Apache poi`

thanks,